# What can cause Exc_Bad_Access on first function call in first VC?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exc-bad-access

Have app in App Store running fine. New version adds a bunch of calculations and minimal new interface. During dev and testing, runs (seemingly) perfectly in Simulator on all devices. Started testing on physical devices, and getting Bad_Access 1 or 2. I read every link on those I could find, and realize it's a difficult error. Using Swift, so no specifically dereferenced pointers of the type mentioned in most links.

Refactored code in many ways over last week. Eventually got it as simple as possible, posted here. My AppDelegate.swift is as basic as possible with no extra stuff or app-specific processing/initialization. The storyboard entry point is a collection view controller of type MainCollectionViewController. In the viewDidLoad method of that controller, the very first statement is a function call to getDrawingInstructions() with parameters. Using default parameter values, and the first two parameters are structs full of CGFloat, Bool, and UIColor.

As you can see, it's crashing as it gets to that func before even entering the func and executing the func's code. The first func call from viewDidLoad of the initial vc.

I've cleaned the build folder and restarted XCode, I'm Swift 5 compliant, I've updated to XCode 11 GM, I've turned on zombies and have no console message. Looking for suggestions on what to try next, 'cause I'm stumped on how I could get screwed up addresses before (seemingly) executing any app-specific code. And remember, this part runs in Simulator and is unchanged from the prior version that ran fine on all devices.

(In different iterations of code, Zombies would yield a console message like `objc[7801]: Class _NSZombie_FBSXPCMessage is implemented in both ?? (0x162585890) and ?? (0x162576dd0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.` That gives me no clue where to look, especially with the `??`.)

Thank you for any insights.

**Edit**: Per suggestions, removed parameters from function (into struct), but the result was the same as before.

**Edit**: Removed first argument to the call, a large struct, and got same result. Also got console message: `objc[8038]: Class _NSZombie__NSCallStackArray is implemented in both ?? (0x163481590) and ?? (0x163480750). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.` Not sure how to use this message.

**Edit**: If the called func is a stub that returns immediately, it is safely processed. So...it's not even entered with a trace if there's code, but it processes if there's an immediate return. Confusing.

**Edit**: Reconfigured yet again to remove all arguments to the function and just initialize them with default values in the function. That crashes with the same error at the same place, the entry point to the function, without reaching any of the initialization statements in the function. So the first statement in viewDidLoad of the primary VC calls a func with no arguments and crashes with a dereferenced pointer or similar memory error without stepping into that func. I'm not sure how to make that even intentionally happen.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: tangential, but rather than passing 50 parameters into a function, why not create one object with the various properties on it into the method and do your assertions inside the method

Comment: Might not be tangential at all. Replace this with passing a single Configuration struct instance and see if things get better or clearer.

Comment: I will try that next (now). They were added incrementally w new versions with no clear point where adding the 4th or 5th or 6th Bool seemed significant enough to reconfigure this. I'll report back any difference it makes. Thanks for taking time to respond.

Comment: Using a configuration struct as function parameter instead of the six booleans did not change the outcome.

Comment: Is this a Debug build or a Release build?

Comment: It's a debug build. I'd never before had a (known) discrepancy be/t a debug build and release build, and so didn't even think in that direction. I created a release build and it worked perfectly. Thank you, matt. I'm now researching all the implications of not being able to debug on a physical device (GameCenter physics engine is painfully slower in Simulator, for example), but thrilled to be moving forward again. Any comment on why one version could exhibit this behavior and the other wouldn't would be be read with appreciation. Regardless, thank you.